# block a page from logged out users and redirect to homepage

Tags: pages, wp-redirect

How am I blocking certain pages from being viewed by logged out users? I have some pages like a dashboard for example that each user has to display their posts an is found in the top level like mysite.com/dashboard. I made a custom template and assigned it to the page "dashboard" but I need to block all non logged in users and limit to author level and up. If the user doesn't meet the criteria then I need to redirect them to the homepage.

I tried placing this at the top of the template but it returned an error.

```
get_currentuserinfo();
if (!( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( 'publish_posts' )) ) {
  wp_redirect(home_url());
  return false;
}
```

But this leaves the error..

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ()

Comment: Please search the site. This has been answered sooooo many times before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hook in earlier, I would probably use `template_redirect`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_74577_redirect' );

function wpse_74577_redirect()
{
    // the code from your question
}
```

Comment: And use a conditional check for the page inside the function?

Comment: Yes, of course. :) `is_page( 'dashboard' )` should do it. I don’t know how exactly you built that page, so I left it out.